# Appendix sections in book class with hyperlinks in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, hyperlink

I want the last few sections of a chapter in a `book` class to be appendices, and their numberings be of the form 1.A, 1.B, etc. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[pdftex,linktocpage,hyperfootnotes,final]{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Unus}

\section{One}

\section{Two}

{
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{chapter}.\Alph{section}}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\section{Appendix 1}

\section{Appendix 2}
}

\end{document}
```

The problem with this is that on the TOC, when I click the link to the first appendix section, I am redirected to the first section ("One"), but I want to be taken to the first appendix ("Appendix 1"); this clearly has to do with my setting the counter `chapter` back to 0, so I wonder is there is a way of either:

1. declaring appendix sections and having proper redirection in the TOC hyperlinks; or
2. modifying the relevant hyperlinks generated in the TOC manually.

I was hoping that by grouping the appendices between braces this would work as intended, but it doesn't. Thanks!!

Comment: In book class (using `\appendix`), appendices are normally chapters.  If you want to put appendices as sections in more than one chapter, use the appendix package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses the appendix package.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[pdftex,linktocpage,hyperfootnotes,final]{hyperref}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Unus}

\section{One}

\section{Two}

\begin{subappendices}
\section{Appendix 1}
\end{subappendices}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 2):

After reading into the doc for `hyperref` I found the existence of its internal macro `\theH<counter>`, which removes this sort of ambiguities. The working code is

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[pdftex,linktocpage,hyperfootnotes,final]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Unus}

\section{One}

\section{Two}

\renewcommand\theHsection{\arabic{chapter}.\Alph{section}} %Use \theHsection instead of \thesection
\setcounter{section}{0}
\section{Appendix 1}
\end{document}
```

Always read the docs!